# Data tables fixed header in bootstrap modal not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datatable, modal-dialog, fixed-header-tables

Am loading a copy of Data table from the parent page into bootstrap modal and am changing the id for the table in modal first. After this am initializing the data table for both the tables differently.  Also making the header fixed with data table constructor FixedHeader().  Same has been working fine for the table in the parent window and not for modal. Table in the Modal has normal header and one more fixed header is loading in parent window itself, while loading the Modal.

Need solutions to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an issue of datatables. Using [scrollY](https://www.datatables.net/examples/basic_init/scroll_y.html) to put the scroll bar inside `<tbody>` could be a workaround as it fixes the header (and footer).